# Resize image have user set width or height javascript calculate and fill width or height

Tags: javascript, image-processing

I have scoured the web and found partial solutions only that mostly are incomplete.

I want a user to be able to rescale an image to a selected size. This would use a form with 2 text boxes one for width and one for height.

Lets say the image is 1000Wx2000H and user wants to rescale to 100Wx200H, that is easy but if he wants to scale to  125W x A, where A is an unknown value for Height. So user would enter 125 in width text box and javascript would calculate the H text box , or visa versa , user fills in height and width is calculated.

Super nice to have an ignore aspect ration check box too that would select itself it width and height are entered!

I can easily enough get the image dimenseions in PHP and in fact I need to post the result back to the page to get it in php to send to imagemagick.

I think I am not the first to want something like this but not finding anything useful enough on searches.

I do not claim to be a JS expert, but at times it is necessary. PHP on the other hand seemed to come more naturally.

Comment: Whenever you are setting just the width, do you want to set the height maintaining the aspect ratio? Also you want the solution in PHP or JS?

Comment: what is the condition to calculate `h`

Comment: i have no need to change aspect ratio. All images are 1:1 pixel ration. it would howevew be nice to include a checkbox to ignore aaspect ratio, so user canener width and height. or that cheknox is selcted/deselected automatically if both text boxes are filled.

Comment: brk, I can get all image data and calculations in PHP and echo them into javascript with no issue. What I need is how to get the box to autofill with the width or height once the other is set. Extra nice to be able to set both with an "ignore aspect ratio" button too.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work with, we have to first calculate the aspect ratio of the actual image and then calculate the `width` or `height` based on given value.  We can make use of `naturalHeight` and `naturalHeight` properties of `Image` element to calculate aspect ratio.

```
let naturalHeight = $img.naturalHeight;
let naturalWidth = $img.naturalWidth;
let aspectRatio = naturalHeight/naturalWidth;

let height = width*aspectRatio;
$heightInput.value = height;
```

The above solution will calculate the height based on given width value. Here is the full solution -

```
<input type="number" id="h" placeholder="Enter height..." onblur="calculateWidth(this.value)">

<input type="number" id="w" placeholder="Enter width..." onblur="calculateHeight(this.value)">


<button onclick="apply()">
  Apply
</button>

<p>
<img id="img" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/707194/pexels-photo-707194.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
</p>
```

```
let $img = document.getElementById('img');
let $heightInput = document.getElementById('h');
let $widthInput = document.getElementById('w');

function calculateHeight(width){
  let naturalHeight = $img.naturalHeight;
  let naturalWidth = $img.naturalWidth;
  let aspectRatio = naturalHeight/naturalWidth;

  let height = width*aspectRatio;
  $heightInput.value = height;
}

function calculateWidth(height){
  let naturalHeight = $img.naturalHeight;
  let naturalWidth = $img.naturalWidth;
  let aspectRatio = naturalWidth/naturalHeight;

  let width = height*aspectRatio;
  $widthInput.value = width;
}

function apply(){

  let height = $heightInput.value;
  let width = $widthInput.value;

  if(height > 0){
    $img.style.height = `${height}px`;
  } else {
    $img.style.height = `auto`;
  }

  if(width > 0){
    $img.style.width = `${width}px`;
  } else {
    $img.style.width = `auto`;
  }
}
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/tFBo8_F1V

Comment: That is not exactly what I am looking for as entering a width does not display the height without clicking "apply" . This would be the same as doing it all in PHP and posting the data back and calculating height. I want to SEE the calculated height in the text box as soon as I enter width.

Comment: Ashvin777 , I appreciate your help, but after looking at this I have no clue how t make the "apply" post it to the same document *resize.php". I believe that is the only way to get them back to php anyway . How do I get the javascript variables to POST  back to PHP,making the "apply" do a POST??

Comment: Also no idea how to stop the JS from resizing image in this. Not a JS guiy here for sure. It has never made sense to me. Also firefox shows rounded numbers while chrome give me many digits beyond decimal. numbers need to be rounded to whole numbers

Comment: Ashvin777 , I got through the rounding on this. I changed   let height =...  to let height = (Math.round(width*aspectRatio)); and same for width . Still have no idea how to get the apply button to become a form submit preferrably by GET method

Comment: If you want to make the POST call, you can pass the values of naturalHeight and naturalWidth in API call and anymore if required. For more reference you can check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score -1):

Working From Ashvin777's post

Changed to

```
$("#crop_x").val(Math.round(cropbox.x));
$("#crop_y").val(Math.round(cropbox.y));
$("#width").val(Math.round(cropbox.w));
$("#height").val(Math.round(cropbox.h));
```

I also discovered that I needed no javascript POST or anything special. A normal HTML POST passed the variables from jcrop along perfectly

I also added the height and width sizes (I set these as PHP variables then if I want I can calculate them for each image and set them from php)

```
$(function() {
    $('#cropbox').Jcrop({ boxWidth: <?php echo $boxwidth;?>, boxHeight: <?php echo $boxheight;?> });
});
```

The user already could override the calculated aspect. If user sets width and height is calculated then height can be overridden, so I chose to always use the "!" ignore aspect option in imagemagick because javascript is already calculating correct aspect and this way it can be overridden, and the values user sees are exactly what will come out in final image.

The only problem I see is that if I load an image in jcrop on first load it is fine. On immediate subsequent loads however I sometimes see two images first the original size , then the set size. If I load another image between loading it the second time, or third time,  problem goes away. Sounds like something is not clearring or flushing out . this happens in Chrome and Firefox. I however see that others have the same issue.